# When Interacting with a DAPP, how can I see what it is passing to Metamask?

Tags: transactions, wallets, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, raw-transaction

I am looking to intercept calls from Dapp to metamask to be able to see what is inside. I would like to be able to see with which contract am I interacting with and what is the transaction data passed to metamask. This in the objective to build a tool to identify better "dangerous" transactions.

To summarize i would like to be able to see the transaction generated by any interaction with a Dapp.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but I'd start modifying metamask, perhaps creating a browser plugin is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you Ismael. Yes that is what I ended up doing :)

Comment: @FracaShaw Did you succeed in getting the transaction info when one is submitted to Metamask? If so, do you mind sharing how you did it?